# Verizon FIOS blocked access to my own server? Visible with VPN

Tags: dns

I rent a sever with Vultr. One of the old WP websites was reported hacked.

While trying to clean it, I began getting `DNS query timed out` on every single website under that server. For example: [deepcorelabs.com](https://deepcorelabs.com) is timing out for me right now even though that's not the hacked website. Just on the same IP.

At first I thought it was Plesk's fail2ban or router's firewall. I've whitelisted my own IP in Plesk and also changed my DNS from CloudFlare to Google then to Default to no avail.

Now, I'm only able to access the server using VPN.

Does that confirm it's Verizon blocking it?

What can I do to fix it or at least find out what's the culprit?

Comment: If you suspect that an ISP is blocking it, you can run a traceroute to your server to see where the route stops. On the Win command line for example: tracert <your domain>